# Find all solutions X for the equation: $\sin(x)-\cos(x) = 2\sqrt2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How can I find $x$ (non-complex number)? Any detailed solution/explanation is welcome :). Thank you in advance.

The equation:

> $\sin(x)-\cos(x) = 2\sqrt2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

I'm still new at trigonometry equations, and every new way to solve this will help me a lot.

Comment: Useful: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt2}=\sin\left(x-\frac\pi4\right)$$
and
$$2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x,$$
so you are solving
$$\sin\left(x-\frac\pi4\right)=\sin2x.$$
But $\sin a=\sin b$ iff either $b-a=2k\pi$ or $a+b=(2k+1)\pi$
for an integer $k$, etc.